# CONSTRUCT query preserving list structure

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a list of three elements like this:

```
<Employee#1> <hasOrderedTasks> [ a rdf:List ; rdf:first <FirstTask> ;
                                 rdf:rest [ rdf:first <SecondTask> ;
                                 rdf:rest [ rdf:first <ThirdTask> ;
                                 rdf:rest rdf:nil ] ] ] .
```

My question is: **how to I return the list (with its structure) using a `CONSTRUCT` type query?**
Note that the list may have a variable number of elements, and the query would need to generalise to that.
I could use something like:

```
CONSTRUCT {
 ?employee <hasOrderedTasks> ?list .
 ?list <hasElement> ?element 
 }
WHERE {
 ?employee <hasOrderedTasks> ?list .
 ?list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?element .
 }
```

However this would destroy the order of my list. I could of course use some aggregation in a subquery to compute the index of elements in the list, but even that would not recreate my list *as is*.
Is there perhaps some other function that can help me? Or is this just not possible in SPARQL?

Comment: that's not gonna work, RDF is just a **set** of triples. You have to preserve the order between the list elements, i.e. you have to add triples between the elements. Like `<nextElement>` as a relation. So you would need an intermediate variable in your property path based triple pattern

Comment: Thank you. I am still not 100% clear how adding an intermediate variable and `<nextElement>` would help. How will the head of the query know where to put the intermediate variable?